# Icon Pack that don't overwrite default application's icon

Tags: theme, icons

Is there an icon pack that don't override the default icons of certain applications?

Or maybe a way to disable this behavior?

Like in this picture, almost all those file manager have the same icons.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Am not sure I understand what you mean. This is the case on a fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such icon theme.

> Is there an icon pack that don't override the default icons of certain applications?

For a file manager, the default icon is `system-file-manager` as per [Icon Naming Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html). For any desktop environment, only one file manager is installed by default and that will use the same icon.

> Like in this picture, almost all those file manager have the same icons.

In the shown picture, PCManFM is using a **default icon** that is found at `/usr/share/icons/THEME`. The default icon appears to be same regardless of icon theme as per specification. Some icon theme such as elementary Xfce does provide `pcmanfm` icon, but that is symlink to the same icon anyway.

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/pcmanfm.desktop | grep Icon
Icon=system-file-manager

$ ls -l /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/apps/48/pcmanfm.png
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Nov  6  2015 /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/apps/48/pcmanfm.png -> system-file-manager.png
```

In contrast, Thunar is using a **fallback icon** that is found in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor` instead of `/usr/share/icons/THEME`. This will happen whenever the installed icon theme does not have the needed icon for certain application, in this case, Thunar.

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/Thunar.desktop | grep Icon
Icon=Thunar

$ ls -l /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/Thunar.png 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4261 Apr  9  2014 /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/Thunar.png

$ ls -l /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/apps/48/Thunar.png
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Nov  6  2015 /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/apps/48/Thunar.png -> system-file-manager.png
```

User will only see a **unique icon** being used for a cross platform or desktop agnostic file manager. A good example is [Double Commander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/), which indeed has its own icon unlike other file managers.

**TL;DR** Most file managers use the same default icon as per specification.